# Solution to a non-linear equation system un Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to solve an arithgram using Matlab. For this, I have proposed a system of 6 non-linear equations with 9 variables, so that system has infinite solutions.
When using the *solve ()* function, the only result I get (because I'm getting only one solution) has rational numbers, when they should all be integers. In fact, I have verified and there is a solution with integers, but I have not been able to figure out how to get that solution with the function.
When I try to use *solve ()* with integer variables (*syms x integer*) hoping to forcing the program to find the solution I'm looking for, Matlab is not able to find a solution for the system at all.
Here is the code I used:

```
syms a b c d e f g h i integer;
ecuacion = solve(a*b*c==vertical(1),d*e*f==vertical(2),g*h*i==vertical(3),a*d*g==horizontal(1),b*e*h==horizontal(2),c*f*i==horizontal(3),a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i);
solucion = eval([ecuacion.a ecuacion.b ecuacion.c;ecuacion.d ecuacion.e ecuacion.f;ecuacion.g ecuacion.h ecuacion.i]);
```

Is there a function I that can help me with this problem? Or Am I doing something wrong?
Here there is a link to my original post in Spanish in case you want to see the arithgram: https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/51725/edit

Comment: Since you need an integer solution you are in difficult territory :-) Even a linear integer program is difficult to solve, let alone a nonlinear one. Is there literature for such classes of problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all equations are of the form a*b*c = d, perhaps you should consider taking logarithms first: A = log(a), B = log(b), C = log(c), so that A + B + C = log(d). This would translate your problem to a linear one.

Comment: Moreover, note that your equations are not independent, the matrix P of the linear problem (after the log-transform), which has dimensions 6x9, has rank 5. Removing one equation might help the algorithm (any algorithm) find a solution.

Comment: That was in fact a very elegant idea, and I have implemented. However, Matlab always gives me the same solution, and is not the one with only integers. If I could find a way to maybe get a matrix where each vector is a solution (maybe with 10, 50 or 100 possible solutions), I could then search for the solution I need. Any ideas?

Comment: @PedroZampella, the problem is actually combinatorial, since the variables are integers. As I said before, you are in difficult territory. I solved the problem with pencil and paper by enumerating the possible values of any variable (if `a*b*c = d` then a, b, and c are divisors of d), then taking intersections (if `a*b*c = d` and `a*e*f = g` then a must divide both d and g). Such observations reduce the search space significantly, so perhaps a program which enumerates all possible solutions (with some clever pruning and backtracking) could be written. But it is not a trivial task to do IMHO.

Comment: Should I use an approach with genetic algorithms?

Comment: I personally don't have any respect for genetic algorithms, I would go with the approach I mentioned. May I ask why you are trying to solve such a problem? Is it for fun? Is it for a class? If so, which?

Comment: It's an Computer Vision project where I need to develope an augmented reality application that is able to solve an arithgram and display the output live and over the original image... And, as you can see, I'm kinda stuck in the arithgram's solution.